# Typeorm : create a query (update) with join and select last element with date

Tags: typeorm

I have a problem to create the query.

I have Two tables :

The models (exemple) :

```
@Entity('table1')
export class Table1 {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Column({ name: 'nom' })
    public nom: string;

    @OneToMany(
        type => Passage,
        passage => passage.domicilie,
        {
            nullable: true,
            cascade: true,
            onUpdate: 'RESTRICT',
            onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
        }
    )
    public passages: Passage[];
}

@Entity('passage')
export class Passage {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'timestamp',
        nullable: false,
        default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    })
    public timestamp: Date;

    @ManyToOne(
        type => Table1,
        table1 => table1.passages,
        {
            nullable: false,
            onUpdate: 'RESTRICT',
            onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
        }
    )
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'table1_id' })
    public table1: Table1;
}
```

I must do a query that get all element in tavble1 but only the lines who have timestamp in passage more than 3 months;

I do this but not works, got error :

```
const date3mois = moment(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(3, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        console.log(date3mois);

        return this.createQueryBuilder('domicilie')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('domicilie.passages', 'p')
            // .where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(domicilie.date_debut)*1000 BETWEEN :dateD and :dateF')
            .where(
                'DATE_FORMAT(MAX(p.timestamp), "%Y%m%d") <= :date3mois',
                { date3mois}
            )
            .andWhere('domicilie.isDisabled = :isDisabled', {
                isDisabled: false,
            })
            .getMany();
```

EDIT : I have the SQL.

```
SELECT
            d.id AS domicilie_id,
            d.numero AS domicilie_numero,
            d.nom AS domicilie_nom,
            d.prenom AS domicilie_prenom
          FROM domicilie d
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT domicilie_id, MAX(`timestamp`) AS date_dernier_passage
              FROM passage
              GROUP BY domicilie_id
            ) t
          ON t.domicilie_id= d.id
          WHERE t.date_dernier_passage < SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
          AND d.status_id <> 1;
```

When I can write it with TypeOrm ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Hello, It seem ike this request I must write into Typeorm ? When I can write it ? The query in SQL : SELECT d.id AS domicilie_id,
 d.numero AS domicilie_numero,
 d.nom AS domicilie_nom,
 d.prenom AS domicilie_prenom
FROM domicilie d
LEFT JOIN 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT p.domicilie_id
 FROM passage p
 WHERE p.`timestamp` > SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
) t
 ON t.domicilie_id = d.id
WHERE t.domicilie_id IS NULL
AND d.status_id <> 1